# Laravel Controller error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning how to do a simple Laravel app, an social network and I came across an error

```
[Fri Aug 26 00:46:30 2016] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Post' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\social-network\app\Http\Controllers\PostController.php on line 13
```

My PostController.php is this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    {

        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $request['body'];
        $request->user()->posts()->save($post);
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }
}
```

My Post model is this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I did wrong. Can anyone help me figure out the error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the model.

Try to add following line in your controller after namespace

```
use App\Post;
```

This is what the error message exactly telling you.

Comment: That was the error I don't need 'App\User', just 'App\Post'. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use tell your controller to use `App\Post`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller{

    public function postCreatePost(Request $request){
        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $request['body'];
        $request->user()->posts()->save($post);
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }
}
```

Also, typically good idea to make sure you run `composer dump-autoload` after adding new classes.

Comment: Yep, anytime! Best of luck.